# Update command line application status

Tags: java, bash

I have a command line application that currently print a percentage being increased.

1%
2%
3%
4%
...

The output is sequential. But I have seen command lines tools that shows the changes as if it being update inline.

1%

2% In the same position as the first

3% In the same position as the first

4% In the same position as the first

¿How can I achieve this?  I am using Java, if that matters, and the application will run on linux.

Thank you.

EDIT

And How do I use colors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Output a `\r` before printing the update, then flush. This will return the cursor to the first column.

Comment: Thank you! That is perfect. ¿And how can I use colors?

Comment: @Nerlan: JCurses looks like a decent entry point to the terminfo library. http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but for those who don't want to use [JavaCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/), I have [written a couple small, lightweight utility classes](http://bitbucket.org/dainkaplan/tempura-utils) for doing both console rewriting and ANSI colourisation. The code is in Scala, but it is callable from Java if the jars are on your classpath; there's a [Java demo app](http://bitbucket.org/dainkaplan/tempura-utils/src/8cce50c145f3f6a43dad4cd06dd0828ce03872f2/src/main/java/org/tempura/console/utils/JavaConsoleDemo.java?at=master) in the source, but it is reproduced below. Output has been verified on OS X and Ubuntu.

```
public class JavaConsoleDemo {
    private final ConsoleWriter screen;
    public JavaConsoleDemo(ConsoleWriter screen) {
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public void rewriteWithColors(String name) throws Exception {
        screen.clearAll();
        screen
                .print(Red().and(BgYellow()).format("Hello"))
                .print(" ")
                .print(Yellow().format("World"));
        screen.display();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        screen.clearAll();
        screen
                .print(Blue().and(BgWhite()).format("Hello"))
                .print(" ")
                .print(Magenta().and(BgBlue()).format("%s", name));
        screen.display();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    public void rewrite(String name) throws Exception {
        screen.clearAll();
        screen.print("Hello\nWorld");
        screen.display();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        screen.clearAll();
        screen.print("Hello\n" + name);
        screen.display();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConsoleWriter screen = new ConsoleWriter(System.out);
        JavaConsoleDemo demo = new JavaConsoleDemo(screen);
        demo.rewrite(args[0]);
        demo.rewriteWithColors(args[0]);
    }
}
```