# display progress in cmd without new lines

Tags: java

I have a java application which run on `cmd`. I want to show progress while running this process. In this application 50 branches processing and I want to show after processed one branch **2%** completed and after another branch processed **4%** completed and so on.
Problem is when I used

```
System.out.print("PROGRESS :" + branch_Vec.get(value).toString()+" : "+ df2.format(((a / total) * 100)) +" % \r");
```

as a out put it goes to new line each time it calls.

I want to show progress in same line.For example:

```
progress : AB : 2%
```

Comment: yo can simply create a thread which queries the current status of the process been completed and keep printing accordingly on console

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I print to the same line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939802/how-can-i-print-to-the-same-line)

Comment: @user714965: this is not a duplicate. Please read the question again.

Comment: This code works for me. Can you create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Its a good question, im interested to see if their is an answer. I fear it is not possible (within reason)

Comment: @defaultlocale which platform are you on? His example doesnt work for me (ie prints each % on a new line)

Comment: @cowls java 1.6_023 windows 7 x64. dummy program updates current line.

Comment: interesting, im running in eclipse, maybe thats my problem.

Comment: @user2164770 Try to run [this code](http://ideone.com/bgipum) from command line. If it works as expected double check your code for newline output. Also, I believe you should specify java and os information.

Comment: @cowls: Yes, Eclipse does not support the carriage return `\r`. The commandline will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `System.out.print("\rComplete: "+percentage);` should just work.

The `\r` is a carriage return, and will clear the current line. As long as you don't write a newline `\n` you can update the text.

Note that this *does not work* in the console in Eclipse, if you're using that to test.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing it, at least in a simple way. The point is that the default `System.out` `OutputStream` either allows you to call `print()`, which prints characters one after another, or `println()`, which does the same as `print()`, but also puts a new line in the end of your text.

One non-elegant solution would be to clear the screen between the updates, so as to make it seem like it is printing in the same position. If you're using windows, for example, this would be:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

Unfortunately, this line is system-dependant, as it calls the `cls` command.

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4207708/451518) to another question. It's possible and OP is talking about unexpected behaviour

Comment: That's interesting! It would have been a problem in old Mac OS (up to version 9) environments, but it will probably work in all platforms nowadays.